# visual-studio-code can't print out 2d array in the console, No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

My visual-studio-code can't print out 2d array in the [the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmgSa.png),it shows No debug adapter, can not send 'variables',my language is nodejs.Is this a bug in vscode?How can i do?

test code:

```
    var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Please describe your question with correct snippet. And What you are facing?

Comment: sorry, this is my first time to use stackoverflow,my problem is my vscode can't print 2d array in the console.u can click the link to see the picture.